# PowerShell script to update field with IDs to media items

Tags: powershell-extensions

Trying to update media item field through script .In the csv file I have item name for uploaded images that needs to be updated in the Imagefield

**script:**

```
 $AllPhotoGallery = Get-ChildItem -Path "master://sitecore/media library/Images/photo-gallery" -Recurse
 $Mediaimage = $AllPhotoGallery   | Where-Object { $_."DisplayName" -eq $PropertyPhotoName  };

        $ID = $Property."Photos"

        $Property.Editing.BeginEdit();
        $Property["Photos"] = $ID;  #Here
```

Field:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My understanding from your sample code is that you want to edit a field which contains 0 or or more item IDs. The [documentation site](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/code-snippets) has some examples for this.

**Example:** The following adds new Ids to an existing list. Makes use of the `Sitecore.Text.ListString` class.

```bsh
[Sitecore.Text.ListString]$ids = $item.Fields["Photos"].Value
$ids.AddAt(0,"{guid1}") > $null
$ids.Add("{guid2}") > $null
$ids.Add("{guid3}") > $null

$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.Fields["Photos"].Value = $ids.ToString()
$item.Editing.EndEdit() > $null
```

Comment: I want to update image from csv to the field

Comment: Please update your question to more succinctly explain the requirements. At the moment it does not clearly indicate that you need to update from a csv, what the csv structure is currently, etc.